# Very strange syntax error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I get a compiler error while trying to access `addMenu.setLayout()`.

> Syntax error on token "setLayout", = expected after this token

Here is my code:

```
JPanel pnl1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,0));
JPanel homeMenu = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,0));
JPanel addMenu = new JPanel();
addMenu.setLayout(new BoxLayout(addMenu, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); // Here is the red underline
```

Comment: Nothing wrong there. How are you compiling this? What ide are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Eclipse? Sometimes it is buggy.

Just do `File >> Save All`.

Comment: fixed it dudes i had te initialise te panel before i could use the layout thanks for the answers

Comment: @stephendelaney I would like to thank you too, and I will do if you add your own answer and accept it to explain to future readers how you have solved that problem.